# JavaFX : Inline CSS button hover effect

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to apply inline hover effect for my buttons.

```
public class scMain implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button view1,view2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    
    }

     @FXML
    void onMouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        view1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        view2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
    }
```

As you might expect, when the mouse is hovered on **view1**, **view2** will also turn white simultaneously. I know that if I create separate MouseEvent, it will work. But is there a shorter way to do this? If I have 10 buttons I have to create 10 MouseEvent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Style your buttons using the `:hover` pseudo class defined in an external stylesheet.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the suggestion. But is there no way to do this inline?

Comment: I don’t recommend that. In initialize put all the buttons in a set using a [lookup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll(java.lang.String)) on a parent. Loop through the button set. In the loop add a listener to the button [hover property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#hoverProperty). In the listener, set or unset the style depending on the new hover state. Seems like an [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: _But is there no way to do this inline?_ Why? Support of hover is standard behavior of buttons, why would you run your own manually (which most probably will collide with the default anyway)?